Does Stack being limited in size mean i can only get limited pointers to objects in heap?
if stack size is 1MB, does that mean i can only get less than 1000000/8 pointers to allocate ints in heap? (considering 1MB free stack) yeah i know you might not want to make that many individual ints on heap but still it limits number of objects you can dynamically allocate.
doesnt that just make making ints on stack better choice? (ints are 4 bytes here)
edit:
i get comments of what usage of pointers are, that not what im asking, what i meant is that with limited stack size, isnt there limited "number", not "size" of stuff you can access/make on heap?

With "if heap size is 1MB" I assume you meant "if stack size is 1MB"? Please [edit] your question to fix any possible typos and other problems it might have.

And if you mean the stack, then the compiler and function calls leading up to the main function will store other data on the stack, so there's less than one MiB available. With that said, what remains can be used to fill up with local variables, and if they are pointers then on a 64-bit system each pointer will use eight bytes. So your calculation is approximately right. Exactly where all these pointers are pointing is rather irrelevant though. They could point to the heap, or the stack, or some other data (like global variables), etc.

yeah thanks for pointing out the typo, also yeah i know about other stuff occupying stack so thats why i said (considering 1MB free stack). yeah it doesnt matter where they point to, i just wanted to say i can only make limited amount of "stuff" dynamically on heap by making pointers on stack

When you allocate an array you have 1 pointer to the array. Not a separate pointer to each individual element.

Also note that if you fill up the stack with local variables, then you can't call any functions, including malloc to create space on the heap.

@drescherjm, yeah in that case i can only make limited amount of "arrays" with the limit being stack size

FYI, pointers are not restricted to items in the heap.  In Embedded Systems, we use pointers to access hardware devices, like a USB driver.

You can allocate an object on the heap and that object can have as many dynamically allocated objects as can fit in the virtual memory space of your process so the stack limitation does not apply in that example.

Stack might be 1 MB by default. Nothing stops you from changing the default for a program that happens to need more space. Why is stack memory size so limited?

FYI, there are compilers and OSes that organize memory so that stack is at one end, the heap at the other end.  They "grow" towards each other.  Thus you can have a huge stack at the risk of minimal heap.

Maybe the confusion is that the OP (correctly) thinks that the result of each dynamic allocation must be stored somewhere; these results are unrelated and cannot be portably simplified to pointer arithmetic. Then, if you want to store the results on the stack, then indeed you have to fit into the available stack space. You can of course store the results somewhere else.

The Stack and the Heap have nothing to do with each other.  The Stack having a limited size simply means that you have a limited amount of space to store things like local variables and function call parameters. That has nothing to do with how much space you can allocate dynamically in the Heap.
For example:
int *ptr1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
int *ptr2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * M);

ptr1 and ptr2 are local variable created on the Stack, but they point to dynamic memory allocated on the Heap. The size of the Stack does not influence how much space is on the Heap:
   Stack                     Heap
+-----------+           +-------------+
|           |           |             |
| +------+  |           |  +--------+ |
| | ptr1 | -|-----------|->| 12345  | |
| +------+  |           |  +--------+ |
| +------+  |           |  | 67890  | |
| | ptr2 | -|-----+     |  +--------+ |
| +------+  |     |     |  | ...    | |
|           |     |     |  +--------+ |
+-----------+     |     |             |
                  |     |  +--------+ |
                  +-----|->| 12345  | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |  | 67890  | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |  | ...    | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |             |
                        +-------------+

It seems you are assuming that having a small Stack means you can only have X number of pointers total into the Heap.  That is not true.  For example, a pointer can be moved from the Stack into an object member that exists in the Heap:
   Stack                     Heap
+-----------+           +-------------+
|           |           |             |
| +------+  |           |  +--------+ |
| | ptr1 | -|-----------|->| member | -----+
| +------+  |           |  +--------+ |    |
| +------+  |           |             |    |
| | ptr2 | -|-----+     |  +--------+ |    |
| +------+  |     |     |  | 12345  | <----+
|           |     |     |  +--------+ |
+-----------+     |     |  | 67890  | |
                  |     |  +--------+ |
                  |     |  | ...    | |
                  |     |  +--------+ |
                  |     |             |
                  |     |  +--------+ |
                  +-----|->| 12345  | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |  | 67890  | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |  | ...    | |
                        |  +--------+ |
                        |             |
                        +-------------+


I belive the confusion revolves around the assumptions that every heap allocation allocates 1 thing, and has 1 pointer on the stack. Therefore putting an upper bounds on the number of total allocations. This answer could be augmented by clarifying that both of those assumptions are false.

You can have one pointer on stack that points to a range of pointers on the heap. Each of those pointers can in turn point to different places on the heap. So practically no.
